# Custom validation logic for Firebase remote config values?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We're using `Firebase Remote Config` to remotely toggle features in our `Android` and `iOS` apps. All top-level app features (imagine menu drawer items) can be toggled by `boolean` config values.

Consequently, it is possible for all features to be accidentally `disabled`, leaving users with an empty shell of an app.

We could add some client-side logic to fallback to a sensible feature configuration, but there are reasons in our case why this isn't straightforward (each feature depends on a server-side module being available).

Is there some way to specify some custom validation rules for `Firebase Remote Config` values? Ideally it would be great if these were server-side, so it weren't possible to publish a change where all feature toggles are disabled in the first place.

Alternatively some kind of client-side validation, but this seems like it would involve creating some kind of local cache to use as the source of truth instead of leveraging Remote Config's built-in local cache + defaults (which doesn't sound great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no kind of server-side validation that you can perform on Remote Config values.

If you think this kind of thing would be useful, I'd encourage you to fill out a Feature Request over at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/. The team reviews these requests pretty regularly.